# Dynamicly Change & Pass variable to partial in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Ok what i have is a Data table that has many records in it and each has there own button to open a dialog box. I want each dialog box to be able to change the data each time thru an AJAX request and is opened to the right data...

Problem is I need the `sub` variable to change dynamically and be different every time the AJAX script is ran..

Works perfectly the first time... but doesn't change on next load.. not sure if it is the Div `replaceWith()` or if it is something else.

Button:

```
<input class="payment_lookup" id="<%= account["account_code"] %>" type="button" value="View Payment Info">
```

Javascript:

```
$(".payment_lookup").on("click", function(event) {
        var id = event.target.id;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/billing/" + id + "/toggle_partial",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#payment_data").dialog("open");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("#payment_data").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: $(window).width()-100,
        buttons: {
            "Close": function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

Routes:

```
  post 'billing/:id/toggle_partial' => "billing#toggle_partial"
```

Controller:

```
  def toggle_partial
    code = params[:id]
    @sub = subscription_info(code)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def subscription_info(paysysid)
    unless paysysid.nil? || paysysid.empty?
      Recurly::Account.find(paysysid)
    end
  end
```

toggle_partial.js

```
$("#payment_data_details").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'payment_data', :sub => @sub )) %>");
```

Also Tried this:

```
$("#payment_data_details").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'payment_data', :locals =>{ :sub => @sub } )) %>");
```

**Update:**

I have logged everything:

everything works perfectly to the toggle_partial.js

`@sub` changes everytime it hits that partial JS file. and it passes the `@sub` to the partial as `sub`

BUT:

once `sub` is set in the view the first time it does not change it on the second request...

**2nd UPDATE...**

Have it Narrowed Down to The `replaceWith()` if i change it to `append()` it appends with the new variable information... but i would rather have it replace the previous information... not actually append....

SOLVED

added `$("#payment_data_details").empty();` into the Onclick Javascript so that it emptys the contents of that div. before it trys to set new.

```
    $(".payment_lookup").on("click", function(event) {
        var id = event.target.id;
        $("#payment_data_details").empty();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/billing/" + id + "/toggle_partial",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#payment_data").dialog("open");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: First thing i would do here is to log out the value of @sub and sub at all stages in the controller, toggle_partial.js and the partial.

Comment: Updated with new info of the logging results